# To round in R with one restriction

Tags: r, rounding

I have this dataset:

```
B <- c(60.65, 25.25)
D <- c(10, 10)
E <- c(30.35, 65.75)
Total <- c(100,100)
```

I want to round columns subject to `B+D+E = 100`

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings!

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're trying to do. Can you explain what exactly you want to happen here?

Comment: I think there are multiple solutions when the original elements do not sum to 100. I am guessing that if the sum is always an overestimate of 100, you might want to use `trunc`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking about how to *scale* entries from `B`, `D`, `E` such that they sum `Total`. The word "round" doesn't make too much sense here in my opinion.

If that is the case, you can do the following

```
df <- data.frame(B, D, E) * Total / rowSums(data.frame(B, D, E))
df
#        B       D        E 
#1 60.0495 9.90099 30.04950 
#2 25.0000 9.90099 65.09901
```

The `data.frame` `df` then contains the scaled column vectors `B`, `D`, `E`. We can confirm that indeed components sum to `Total`

```
rowSums(df)
#[1] 100 100
```

Comment: I think the aim is to obtain integers, so after scaling to 100, columns B and D should be rounded, and E calculated as 100 minus sum of B and D.

Comment: @GrzegorzSionkowski That's not very clear from OPs post. As to your interpretation: Why calculate `E = 100 - (round(B) + round(D))`, why not `B = 100 - (round(E) + round(D))` or `D = 100 - (round(B) + round(E))`? All of these will give you slightly different rounded values for `B`, `D`, `E`. Do you see where I'm going?

Comment: I am talking about subtraction, because there may be such a case that simple rounding after scaling might not give the sum equal 100.

Comment: @GrzegorzSionkowski Yes I understood your point; what I was showing you is that your "subtraction" method is ambiguous and can produce different rounded `B`, `D`, `E` values depending on *how* you subtract.

Comment: The arbitrarily chosen column is a solution for the case when simple rounding of scaled B, D, E doesn't give the sum equal to 100. Very rare case.

Comment: @GrzegorzSionkowski *"Arbitrarily chosen column is a solution"* I think we're getting ahead of ourselves here. I don't think your subtraction method is very sound, from a mathematical point of view this is a simple scaling transformation. But let's wait for OP to clarify on his goal.

Answer (score 0):

Sums of row values are close to 100 but simple rounding does not always give 100, e.g. the first row.
So, before rounding, let's perform scaling which changes the sum of the row values from 'close' to exactly equal to 100. However, there may occur such situation, that even rounding after scaling doesn't give the sum equal 100, so let's correct this by changing the values of one of the columns:

```
# additional value 100/3
B <- c(60.65, 25.25, 100/3)
D <- c(10, 10, 100/3)
E <- c(30.35, 65.75, 100/3)
Total <- c(100, 100, 100) 

df <- round(data.frame(B, D, E)*100/rowSums(data.frame(B, D, E)))

df
#   B  D  E
#1 60 10 30
#2 25 10 65
#3 33 33 33

rowSums(df)
#[1] 100 100  99

df[,3] <- 100 - rowSums(df[,1:2])

df
#   B  D  E
#1 60 10 30
#2 25 10 65
#3 33 33 34

rowSums(df)
#[1] 100 100 100
```